# Jquery load State and City value according to selection from certain url

Tags: jquery, onchange

I have the following code:

```
   <label for="ItemCountry">Country <span class="req">*</span></label>
    <select name="ItemCountry" id="ItemCountry" class="cat_dropdown" />
     <option value="AU" selected="selected">Australia</option>
     <option value="CA">Canada</option>
     <option value="CN">China</option>
     <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
     <option value="RU">Russia</option>
     <option value="US">United State</option>
   </select>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#ItemCountry').change(function() {
var CountryVal = this.value; // value of the select element
$("#StateFeeder").html('<img src="/images/mapCountry/AU/ajax-loader.gif" class="IMG-Loading" />');
$('#StateFeeder').load('/StateFeeder/StateFeeder-Buy.html #StateFeeder-'+CountryVal);
})
})               
</script>

<div id="StateFeeder">
  <label for="ItemState">State / Province <span class="req">*</span></label>
  <select name="ItemState" id="ItemState" class="cat_dropdown">
    <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
    <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
    <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
    <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
    <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
    <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
    <option value="WA">WA</option>
    <option value="SA">SA</option>
    <option value="NT">NT</option>
  </select>e.g. NSW
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
     $('#ItemState').change(function() {
         var StateVal = this.value; // value of the select element
         $("#CityFeeder").html('<img src="/images/mapCountry/AU/ajax-loader.gif" class="IMG-Loading" />');
         $('#CityFeeder').load('/Country/'+CountryVal+'/_'+CountryVal+'_suburbs.html #Suburbs-'+StateVal, function(){
         $('#CityFeeder select').attr('size', '5');
         $('#CityFeeder select').change(function(){  this.form['CAT_Custom_221342'].value=$(this).val();
         }); });        
     })
  })               
</script>
    <div id="CityFeeder">
    <label for="ItemCity">City / Suburb <span class="req">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="ItemCity" id="ItemCity" class="cat_textbox" maxlength="255" style="text-transform: capitalize;" />e.g. Chatswood
    </div>
```

**the last part is not working, which it suppose to pass the value of state selection into the url to load certain city dropdown stored from that state block in remote url, it seems that the "CountryVal" is not taking value into that url, please help me to correct it, many thanks:**

```
$('#CityFeeder').load('/Country/'+CountryVal+'/_'+CountryVal+'_suburbs.html #Suburbs-'+StateVal, function(){
    $('#CityFeeder select').attr('size', '5');
    $('#CityFeeder select').change(function(){
        this.form['CAT_Custom_221342'].value=$(this).val();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: `CountryVal` has bad scope, it's not visible from `load()`, you can add `var CountryVal = $('#ItemCountry').val();` juste before `var StateVal = //...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to move the $('#ItemState').change(function(){...}) inside the $('#StateFeeder').load("..") so that when the first load finishes, it binds the change event to the new dom element. Also try to include all the scripts inside a single  tag under a $(document).ready(function(){...})

```
<label for="ItemCountry">Country <span class="req">*</span></label>
<select name="ItemCountry" id="ItemCountry" class="cat_dropdown" />
    <option value="AU" selected="selected">Australia</option>
    <option value="CA">Canada</option>
    <option value="CN">China</option>
    <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
    <option value="RU">Russia</option>
    <option value="US">United State</option>
</select>

<div id="StateFeeder">
    <label for="ItemState">State / Province <span class="req">*</span></label>
    <select name="ItemState" id="ItemState" class="cat_dropdown">
        <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
        <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
        <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
        <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
        <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
        <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
        <option value="WA">WA</option>
        <option value="SA">SA</option>
        <option value="NT">NT</option>
    </select>e.g. NSW
</div>

<div id="CityFeeder">
    <label for="ItemCity">City / Suburb <span class="req">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="ItemCity" id="ItemCity" class="cat_textbox" maxlength="255" style="text-transform: capitalize;" />e.g. Chatswood
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var CountryVal;
var StateVal;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ItemCountry').change(function(){
        CountryVal = this.value; // value of the select element
        $("#StateFeeder").html('<img src="/images/mapCountry/AU/ajax-loader.gif" class="IMG-Loading" />');
        $('#StateFeeder').load('/StateFeeder/StateFeeder-Buy.html #StateFeeder-'+CountryVal, function(){
            $('#ItemState').change(function(){
                StateVal = this.value; // value of the select element
                $("#CityFeeder").html('<img src="/images/mapCountry/AU/ajax-loader.gif" class="IMG-Loading" />');
                $('#CityFeeder').load('/Country/'+CountryVal+'/_'+CountryVal+'_suburbs.html #Suburbs-'+StateVal, function(){
                    $('#CityFeeder select').attr('size', '5');
                    $('#CityFeeder select').change(function(){  
                        this.form['CAT_Custom_221342'].value=$(this).val();
                    }); 
                });        
            })
        });
    });
});           
</script>
```

Comment: Glad it did, did not have the time to actually test the code when I wrote!